# How to parse all JSON strings in a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

I have 1 JavaScript object like this:

```
result = {
  "status": "success",
  "message": "Get successful!",
  "data": {
      "name":"Hello world",
      "school": {
          "name":"LHP",
          "address":"HCM"
      },
      "class": "[{\"text\":\"Math\",\"code\":\"math124\"},{\"text\":\"Libra\",\"code\":\"libra124\"}]",
      "student": "{\"time_range\":{\"type\":\"select\",\"text\":\"Today\",\"value\":[{\"code\":\"in_today\",\"text\":\"In Today\"}]}}"
  }
}
```

So I have to parse class and student separately:

```
result.data.class = JSON.parse(result.data.class);
result.data.student = JSON.parse(result.data.student);
```

Is there other way to parse the whole result variable or make this step shorter/better?

Thanks

Comment: There is only one correct way to do this: Do not stringify it in the first place.

Comment: Fix the problem at the root: don't double-encode in the first place.

Comment: Do you need to auto-detect JSON in any arbitrary location or JSON will always be under the same keys?

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the data property's children and parse them.

```
for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(result.data).length; i++) {
    try {
        result.data[Object.keys(result.data)[i]] = JSON.parse(result.data[Object.keys(result.data)[i]]);
    } catch (error) {} // it's already JSON
}
```

But I'd only do that if you're sure you'll only ever have to deal with stringified JSON in the `data` property of your object.

Comment: `if (!isJSON) { [...] JSON.parse(item); }` seems very counterintuitive.

Comment: `try { result[...] = JSON.parse(item); } catch (e) { /* shrug */ }` would be the much more straight forward way of using an exception…

Comment: Fair enough! It was still early... ;-)